# Do calculation on asp.net dropdownlist control change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-select

I have this html mark up:

```
<div class="table">
            <div class="col1 right">Start:

            </div>
            <div class="col2outer center">
                <div class="col2mid">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartHour" runat="server" onchange="Calculate();">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div class="col2side">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMinute" runat="server" onchange="calculateTime()">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="col1 right">Finish:

            </div>
            <div class="col2outer center">
                <div class="col2mid">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFinishHour" runat="server" onchange="Calculate();">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div class="col2side">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFinishMinute" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>

 </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="margin1">
            <h4>total</h4>
             <h3><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">0</asp:Literal></h3>
             <h4>hrs</h4>
    </div>
```

I would like to do a calculation on client side when user selection changes. I have seen many posts trying to do this using normal html element. But in my case I need to use asp.net control. I tried to use this javascript (http://jsfiddle.net/VnwF7/4/) code but it doesn't work with asp.net control.

```
function Calculate() {
    //get values
    var valuestart = $("#<%= ddlStartH.ClientID %>").val();
var valuestop = $("#<%= ddlFinishH.ClientID %>").val();

//create date format          
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();

var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart - 0.5;

$('#<%= lblDuration.ClientID %>').val(hourDiff);

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$('#<%= lblDuration.ClientID %>').text(hourDiff);`   ??????????

Comment: also don't you think it is `$('#ddlStartHour')` instead of `$("#<%= ddlStartH.ClientID %>")`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think it needs to have clientID cause it is an asp.net control. Not html element.

Comment: @asplearning check the actual id of the element using your browser developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart + ":00:00").getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop + ":00:00").getHours();
```

instead of:

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();
```